# How can i make sure the values in my matrix do not repeat within and amongst rows?

Tags: r, function

I need to write a function in R that has no input but randomly selects a set of 13 pairs of letters.
And the output of such function has to be a 2 x 13 matrix. But the letters can appear only once, meaning they cannot be repeated within a row or amongst rows.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
f <- function(){
 x <- letters[1:26]
return(matrix(sample(x,13, replace = F), 2, 13))
}
```

I've managed to make sure letters do not repeat within a row (with replace = F), but I don't know how to make sure letters from one row do not appear again in the other row.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `matrix(sample(letters), 2)`. The `sample`-function creates a vector of length 26 out of the letters without replacement. So there aren't any repetitions. `matrix(..., 2)` creates a matrix with two rows out of your vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to generate two vectors

```
x <- letters[1:26]

matrix(sample(x,26,replace = F),2,13)

         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
    [1,] "s"  "m"  "h"  "z"  "q"  "y"  "w"  "x"  "p"  "n"   "e"   "o"   "j"  
    [2,] "r"  "b"  "d"  "v"  "u"  "a"  "k"  "i"  "f"  "l"   "g"   "c"   "t"
```

Here is the shorthand version

```
x <- letters

matrix(sample(x),2)
```